# colocar un fondo diferente si esta el estado pagado o pendiente

Tags: php, mysql, sql

como realizo la condición para que el estado si es pagado de un color y si esta pendiente de otro tono ya que si esta pendiente me sigue dando el mismo color.
El código es el siguiente:
Muchas gracias.

```html
<?php
  require '../dbcon.php';
  
  $identificacion = $_GET['identificacion'];
  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM afiliados WHERE identificacion = '$identificacion'";
  $resultado = $connection->query($sql);
  $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM enemar WHERE afiliado = '$identificacion'";
  $resultado = $connection->query($sql);
  $row1 = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($estado='pagado'){$text_estado="Pagada";$label_class='label-success';}
      else{$text_estado="Pendiente";$label_class='label-warning';}
?>

<html lang="es">
  <head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylemenu.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container pt-5" >
      
         <h3 class="text-center ">Datos</h3><br>
         Identificacion: <strong><?php echo $row['identificacion']; ?></strong>
         Nombre Completo: <strong><?php echo $row['nombres']." ".$row['apellidos']; ?></strong><hr>
       
        <h3 class="text-center ">Pagos-Periodo</h3><br>
Enero-marzo: <strong><span class="label <?php echo $label_class;? >">
<?php echo $text_estado; ?></span></strong><hr>
        
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

esto es lo que quiero realizar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando un solo operador = cuando para comparar se usan == ya que de lo contrario al usar solo uno estas asignando el valor de la derecha a la variable de la izquierda

Answer (score 4):

intetalo asi: a lo mejor no esta colocando los espacios!

```
<?php
  require '../dbcon.php';

  $identificacion = $_GET['identificacion'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM afiliados WHERE identificacion = '$identificacion'";
  $resultado = $connection->query($sql);
  $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM enemar WHERE afiliado = '$identificacion'";
  $resultado = $connection->query($sql);
  $row1 = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($estado=='pagado'){$text_estado="Pagada";$label_class='label label-warning';}
      else{$text_estado="Pendiente";$label_class='label label-success';}
?>



  <body>
    <div class="container pt-5" >

         <h3 class="text-center ">Datos</h3><br>
         Identificacion: <strong><?php echo $row['identificacion']; ?></strong>
         Nombre Completo: <strong><?php echo $row['nombres']." ".$row['apellidos']; ?></strong><hr>

        <h3 class="text-center ">Pagos-Periodo</h3><br>
Enero-marzo: <strong><span class="<?php echo $label_class;?>">
<?php echo $text_estado; ?></span></strong><hr>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y el error de los símbolos que le mencione lo pasaste igual

Comment: no me percate muchas gracias